# You have 3 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pycharm

I've just created Django project and ran the server.
It works fine but showed me warnings like

```
You have 14 unapplied migration(s)...
```

Then I ran

```
python manage.py migrate
```

in the terminal. It worked but showed me this

```
?: (1_7.W001) MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES is not set.
    HINT: Django 1.7 changed the global defaults for the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.
django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware, django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware, and django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware were removed from the defaults. If your project needs these middleware then you should configure this setting.
```

And now I have this warning after starting my server.

```
You have 3 unapplied migration(s). 
Your project may not work properly until you apply
the migrations for app(s): admin, auth.
```

So how do I migrate correctly to get rid of this warning?

I am using PyCharm and tried to create the project via PyCharm and terminal and have the same issue.

```
~$ python3.5 --version
Python 3.5.2

>>> django.VERSION
(1, 10, 1, 'final', 1)
```

Comment: have you tried 

    python manage.py makemigrations
    python manage.py migrate

Comment: @Dimitris yes. python manage.py makemigrations shows same warning
"MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES is not set..."
Nothing changes.

Comment: And *have* you actually set MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES?

Comment: in your settings.py file do you have this setting ? 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/http/middleware/

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

Comment: @Dimitris I do:
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have not. But when I set it python says it is deprecated.

Comment: you try to run a django project ver 1.7 with django version 1.10  the error you posted says to remove these middleware settings from middleware in your settings.py

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Please state *exactly* how you are creating the project, using which interpreter and how you are running it. As Dimitris says this is probably due to the fact that you are mixing django versions (i.e. you created the project for django version X but you are trying to run it using django version Y).

Comment: @Dimitris Thanks for your time.
So in setting.py in comment on top it says 
"Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.1."

and when I run server it says 
"Django version 1.10.1, using settings 'website.settings'"

So it looks like it is the same Django version. How do I check it in Pycharm?

Comment: ok  , so create a new project
django-admin.py startproject mysite
enter mysite folder
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver

the server should start without errors

Comment: @Dimitris It did not work, but I know my problem now. I used wrong python version for migration. So python3.5 manage.py migrate solves it. But thank you anyway)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So my problem was that I used wrong python version for migration.

```
python3.5 manage.py migrate
```

solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using wrong django version. You need `django1.10`